# TextInput with TextAlign on iOS does not add ellipsis instead wraps [React Native]

Tags: ios, react-native

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import {Text, TextInput, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <View>
        <Text>Text Input without alignment</Text>
        <TextInput style={{padding: 10, margin: 20, borderColor: 'grey', borderWidth: 1}}/>
        <Text>Text Input with right alignment</Text>
        <TextInput textAlign={'right'} style={{padding: 10, margin: 20, borderColor:  'grey', borderWidth: 1}}/>
      </View>
      <TextInput/>
    </View>);
};

export default App;
```

Write some long text into the first field with spaces.

[image]

Write similar text into the second field.

[image]

Unfocus second input
Expected: both fields will have ellipsis at the end
Actual: second input with textAlign doesn't have ellipsis.

Android app works in a different way:
It never shows ellipsis but if you type a long string it always shows the end of it and never beginning. I guess it should move to begin when unfocused.

react: 16.11.0 => 16.11.0
react-native: 0.62.1 => 0.62.1

I have created an issue on github but haven't got any response yet. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29068